# ImportError: cannot import name 'mnist' from 'keras.datasets' (unknown location)

Tags: python, keras

I am using Conda and have installed Keras. When I go to run the code below, I get an error:

```py
# load data
from keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

The error is:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'mnist' from 'keras.datasets' (unknown location)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/tc/519vfm453fj_x5bmd8pwx9480000gn/T/ipykernel_21667/848854869.py in <module>
      1 # load data
----> 2 from keras.datasets import mnist
      3 
      4 (X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()

ImportError: cannot import name 'mnist' from 'keras.datasets' (unknown location)
```

Any suggestions to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`load_data()` function requires a path argument to tell the system where to cache the dataset locally (relative to ~/.keras/datasets) when you run this code on your machine.
You can take reference from official documentation here https://keras.io/api/datasets/mnist/

Comment: The argument is not required and has nothing to do with an ImportError.

Answer (score 0):

With [TensorFlow v. 2.11](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data)

`pip install tensorflow`

`from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist`